# mybatis RuntimeSQLException vs SqlSessionException

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to convert ibatis code to mybatis. my ibatis code is like

```
try {
    sqlMap.insert("insertinfo", insertData);
}
catch (SQLException sqle) {
    Logger.error("error occurred while inserting",sqle);
}
```

Now on mybatis,

```
try {
        session.insert("insertinfo", insertData);
    }
    // what exception to catch ?? RuntimeSQLException or SqlSessionException
     catch ( ?? sqle) {
        Logger.error("error occurred while inserting",sqle);
    }
```

I tried to use both `RuntimeSQLException`  and  `SqlSessionException` and both are working fine. But I don't know which one to use.

Comment: Does anyone have any answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post while I was searching similar issue with mybatis. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166153/how-to-catch-sqlexception-in-mybatis) is the original question I had. Based on comments and my own research I am trying to give answer.

`SQLException` is checked exception and Mybatis only support `RuntimeException` so you cannot use `SQLException` with mybatis.

`SqlSessionException` is RuntimeException used by Mybatis. [refer this](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/exceptions/IbatisException.html)

`RunTimeSQLException` is basically a wrapper over the SQLException to facilitate passing of actual SQLException i.e the one thrown by the JDBC driver unlike others which are exceptions related to Mybatis operations [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166153/how-to-catch-sqlexception-in-mybatis?noredirect=1#comment81321231_47166153)