# How to catch SQLException in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, sqlexception

I am trying to catch `SQLException` on mybatis but it is not allowing me to use this.

```
try{
session.insert("insertMyData", insertData);
}
catch (SQLException sqle) {  // mybatis not supporting SQLException 
   //exception handling code 
}
```

so instead I try to use `SqlSessionException`

```
try{
session.insert("insertMyData", insertData);
}
catch (SqlSessionException sqle) {  // mybatis support this
  //exception handling code 
}
```

but the issue using this is is not all SQL exceptions are caught. if I try to insert duplicate data it is not catching `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`

Is there a way to catch all SQL exception in mybatis.

Comment: Have you checked the case of `SqlSessionException`?

Comment: it won't even go inside catch block.

Comment: Unless all of the mybatis exception have a common base class, there is no way to catch them all with one catch statement. What is the base class of SqlSessionException ?

Comment: • java.lang.Object
--> java.lang.Throwable
--> java.lang.Exception
--> java.lang.RuntimeException
--> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.IbatisException
--> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException
--> org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionException

Comment: just have a catch all block like `catch(Exception ex) { } `

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla that will catch all exception and then I have to dig through exception to find out what kind of exception is it. I was looking for some better solution if any. Thanks though.

Comment: Why would you want to dig through the exception?? Handling the code based on exceptions is not the right way. To check for duplicate date if you are in MySQL there is a way to `insert on duplicate update` on other DBs better check if its already available. Anyways what do you plan to do in the exception block? Looks like all MyBatis exceptions are RunTime exceptions

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla yes all Mybatis exceptions are runtime and that is what I really don't like. I have to dig out through exception to figure out exact cause to handle exception properly as we have that kind of requirements. Thank you for your response.

Comment: [This](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/exceptions/IbatisException.html) is the super exception for all MyBatis related exceptions :) So from here you can know what are the different exception classes MyBatis has

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla if you look my previous comment I already mention exception hierarchy. Still it would not catch checked exception.

Comment: Update!! I found `com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.RuntimeSQLException` Any Idea why there is different set of runtime exception if all mybatis exception are runtime exception

Comment: `RunTimeSQLException` is basically a wrapper over the `SQLException` to facilitate passing of actual `SQLException` i.e the one thrown by the JDBC driver unlike others which are exceptions related to Mybatis operations.